# Regex for string must not contain comma, semi comma, slash etc

Tags: regex, xml, aem

I am working on a piece of regex, which a string must not contain characters * / : [ ] |

Here is my own try out but it does not really working

```
regex="/^[^*/:[]|]+/"
```

The purpose of this regex is actually for one of the Adobe CQ component I am developing. The requirement is if author type in any characters like  * / : [ ] | in dialog textfield, give warning.
The full dialog xml code showing as below:

```
<fieldConfig
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        allowBlank="false"
        regex="/^[^*/:[]|]+/"
        regexText="Please enter a valid character"
        xtype="textfield"/>
```

I couldn't get the regex working properly.

Comment: escape `[]` `regex="/^[^*/:\[\]|]+/"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that all you need is to escape the `[` and `]` inside a character class add a `$` (end of string) anchor:

```
regex="/^[^*\/:\[\]|]+$/"
```

If the regex can be passed as a string, then an equivalent is `regex="^[^*/:\\[\\]|]+$"`.

The end of string `$` anchor makes sure that the *whole* string does not contain the characters inside the character class. It only checked if a substring at the beginning of the string contained no forbidden symbols.

Comment: umm.. as i am typing character into textfield, there is no warning from regex...so it doesnt seem working..

Comment: I guess the problem was with the unescaped forward slash. Please retry with `regex="/^[^*\/:\[\]|]+$/"`. If it does not work, double the backslashes: `regex="/^[^*\\/:\\[\\]|]+$/"`. Please let me know if either of the above mentioned variants works.